# How to export data from Postgresql to mongoDB using java code?

Tags: java, json, mongodb, postgresql

i am trying to export data from postgresql database to MongoDB.I have successfully created string in JSON format and when i store this json in mongoDB collection, only first entry get stored.
here is my code:
public class jsonTobson {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Connection con = null;
    Statement st = null;

    try{
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5544/ddc", "postgres", "aman");
        st = con.createStatement();

        String sql = "select row_to_json(judge_info) FROM dp.judge_info order by judge_idno";

        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        int columnCount = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();

        while (rs.next()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < columnCount;) {
                builder.append(rs.getString(i + 1));
                if (++i < columnCount) builder.append(",");
            }
            builder.append("\r\n");
        }
        String resultSetAsString = builder.toString();



        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
        DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "mongoTest" );
        DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("newTable");
        Set<String> colls = db.getCollectionNames();

        for (String s : colls) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }


    DBObject dbObject = (DBObject)JSON.parse(resultSetAsString);

    coll.insert(dbObject, WriteConcern.NORMAL);                     
        DBCursor cursorDocJSON = coll.find();
        while (cursorDocJSON.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(cursorDocJSON.next());
        }       

            rs.close();
            st.close();
            con.close();
        } catch ( Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println(e.getClass().getName()+": "+e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        } finally {
        }


    }


}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you're building valid objects. There's no array being built to insert multiple rows, and/or you're not looping through the results to insert each row as a document.

Comment: can you post the output of String resultSetAsString = builder.toString();

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Connection con = null;
    Statement st = null;

    try{
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5544/ddc", "postgres", "aman");
        st = con.createStatement();

        String sql = "select row_to_json(judge_info) FROM dp.judge_info order by judge_idno";

        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

        MongoClient mongoClient=null;
            try {
                mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        DB db = mongoClient.getDB("mongoTest");
        System.out.println("Connect to database successfully");

        while (rs.next()) {
                DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("newTable");
                System.out.println("Collection selected successfully");

                BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject("data", rs.getString(1));

                coll.insert(doc);
                }
        } catch ( Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println(e.getClass().getName()+": "+e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        } finally {
        }
    }
}
```